# Why do I have an error: "Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key" when trying to make a request in react App?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http

So I'm using Movies API from TMDB API, and my code looks like this:

```
let apikey = '{my_apikey}';
  let url: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/apikey=';
  url = url + apikey;

  console.log(url);
  (async function () {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
  })()
```

If I insert the url along with my API it displays the data just fine, but when I'm doing it from my app, I have the next error:
[image]

I can't figure out what could be the problem, cause my api key is fine and I copied it from the website.

Comment: With `let apikey = '{my_apikey}';`, is your API key in curly braces? I.e. is `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/apikey=` followed by an api key, or is the api key wrapped in curly braces?

Comment: no no, my api key is not in curly braces, i just wrote it as an example, so that's why i'm confused

Comment: Hmm ok, I would be inclined to believe the error message. Are you definitely sure the API key is correct? What happens when you go to `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/apikey=yourApiKey`?

Comment: i've done it and i get the same error. it's weird cause i used two api keys, and the second one i used previously, so it should be 100% working

Comment: It's `api_key=`, not `apikey=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/authentication). The URL should look something like this:

`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key=<<api_key>>`

Comment: thank you, i guess i just didn't use original url properly, i'll have to learn about it more i think

Comment: I an glad it worked. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue,there was some issue with my .env file i think,i typed the token manually and it worked.

```
const TMDB_TOKEN = "<Access_Token>";
```

before i was importing it from .env file

```
const TMDB_TOKEN = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_TMBD_TOKEN
```